# Deploy Flask App to production without source code

Tags: python-3.x, flask, deployment, build

I've developed a flask app with multiple endpoints like pages and API's with BD connections and "sensible data" like passwords and others.

Im already running the app using `debug=False` and with a config.py with production configs.

Now I ran into a problem. I want to deploy this app in my client server but I dont want to have the source code visible to the client.

In React there is a build and in ASP.NET there is coderush, that can be compiled in a way to hide the source code but I cant find anything related in Flask.

It is possible to create an executable file to compile and encrypt or somehow hide the source code in the client server?

What I've tryed so far:

- encrypt some files and run the project
- create a script to run and install everything
- set environment variables and remove them from the files (this was the only successeful but anyone can still check the environment variables with a few knowledge)

Answer (score 1):

You can ship only the bytecode of your project using tools like PyInstaller or cx_Freeze. This makes it harder to reverse engineer your source code.

Another way to make it harder for the client to get your code from the server is to containerize your app and to publish the image in a private registry and deploy it in the server, this way you have more space to structure your code in a way you only can understand

Comment: like run the app in a container and deploy the container image?

Comment: Yes, you will run your app in container and deploy it in the client server, this means that the client server should have docker engine to be able to run your container.
It's worth saying that doing so to have no guarantee that your code is hidden 100% from the client because he still has the possibility to access your container while running and what's inside but with a little of ninja structuring you can make it hard for even technical people

Comment: using py installer the exe cant import any module that i have installed

Comment: did you verify that spec used by pyinstaller  is suitable for your project ? have a look at this : https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html